# How to access a return value from a node script in BASH?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

Let's say I have a bash script that calls a node script. I've tried to do it like this:

b.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
v=$(node app.js)
echo "$v"
```

app.js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
function f() {
   return "test";
}
return f();
```

How do I access the value returned by the node script ("test") from my bash script ?

Comment: You can't return a value from a script, your example is just calling a function and the return value is thrown away because it does nothing...

Comment: the `test` is returned to the `main` and it isn't printed to the output, so here is nothing to capture... You need output the returned value...

Comment: What you guyz are saying makes sense. However, how do I go about capturing what was printed by the node script into a BASH variable ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

@Daniel Lizik gave an good answer (now deleted) for the part: how to output the value, e.g. using his answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
function f() {
   return "test";
}
console.log(f())
```

And for the part *how to capture the value in bash*, do exactly as in your question:

```
#!/bin/bash
val=$(node app.js)
echo "node returned: $val"
```

the above prints:

```
node returned: test
```

Comment: what if I'm also using console log in the function? And I want the returning value, not all the console log values?

Comment: @MoroSilverio Could you write the output from the function to a file then read the file from Bash?

Comment: @DoomGoober That should be an answer

Comment: The answer is wrong. If your Node script contains multiple console.logs $val will have the value of all those console.logs. This is not what the OP requested. console.logs inside the script should be ignored and $val should only contain the value of the return statement

Answer (score 7):

You can write output to the stdout with `process.stdout.write`

b.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
v=$(node app.js)
echo "$v"
```

app.js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
function f() {
  return "test";
}
process.stdout.write(f());
```