# Is it possible to return the result of javascript method while executing that in shell script?

Tags: javascript, shell

I am new to javascript. I have a js file something like below(test.js):

```
async function getData() {
   let a =100;
   // Some other function calls which modifies a
   // Some more console logs here.
   return a;
}
(async () => {
  console.log(await getData()); // When trying to return await getData() giving some error.
})();
```

I am executing the above script `output = $(node test.js)` in shell script and I need the value of `a` in the shell script but here I am getting all the console.log statements. Is it possible to get the value?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43169153/7865759) answer maybe help you

Comment: I tried that, but it also printing all console log statements along with the returned value.

Comment: is it because of the spaces? shell is very picky about spaces, pls make sure it's `output=$(node test.js)` and there is no space around the `=` sign

Comment: Have a look at [process.stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout). With stdout you print out stuff so that it can be used by other application. Maybe this can also help: [bash - How to handle stdout in node.js - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143704/how-to-handle-stdout-in-node-js)

Comment: can you add `shell` script to question?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that output will always have one line (by output I mean returned value from `getData()`), you can use `$(node test.js | tail -n 1)` to grab only one last line from `node test.js`. Otherwise you can do this little hacky workaround by replacing `console.log` function:

```
async function getData() {
   let a = 100;
   console.log("Some cosole log");
   console.log("Some other log");
   return a;
}
(async () => {
        console_log = console.log; // Save original function for later
        console.log = ()=>{}; // Replace original with "dummy" function
        console_log(await getData()); // Use saved original to log only what we want
})();
```

This will work unless some part of code use `process.stdout.write` to log/print data directly. To avoid this, we can again replace `process.stdout.write` with some dummy function but since this is likely to break some other things, I would avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can use one of them. I am more inclined to ```$(node test.js | tail -n 1)```

Comment: How to get the data if the variable returned in multi-line string variable?

Comment: If I try to use ```console_log = console.log; ``` it's saying void function return value is used.

Comment: I assume it's just a warning from the IDE so it will be fine at runtime (as in JS you are allowed to use "void values" (functions without a return statement) as assignments). If this message bother you (like it would bother me), you can probably find some way to suppress this warning/error.